# Web search with Alfred create new tab or new window randomly

Tags: safari, alfred

I use google search with Alfred, but after I press 'Enter', sometime the searched content shows up in a new tab in Safari, which is what I prefer. But sometime a new window of safari is created without any reason. What should I do to avoid a new window? I've already set in the preference of Safari 'Open pages in tab instead of windows' to be 'Always'.